# How to recover files deleted by System Restore

Tags: windows-8, data-recovery, system-restore

My buddy has done a System Restore to recover his laptop. This System Restore deleted a whole bunch of Javascript files in his My Documents folder belonging to a project he was working on. They were not yet checked out in SVN.

What are the steps, if any, we can take to recover these files?

Comment: It's simple he reverses his decision to accept the changes

Comment: @Ramhound, I see I haven't posted a reply here yet, but I didn't know of the possibility to undo system restore. So your suggestion solved our problem. If you post it as an answer I can mark it as accepted.

Comment: btw system restore point normaly only affects system data/files and to personal data stored on the hard drive. Its first time i hear that files in "my documents" will change as well.

Answer (score 1):

Performing System Restore will create an 'Undo' restore point of the state before restoring. You could thus undo the whole System Restore, but that will put you back in the situation with the system problems you were trying to correct. Better is to use [Shadow Explorer](http://www.shadowexplorer.com/) to selectively resurrect your reverted or deleted user files from the 'Undo' restore point, either as individual files or as a whole directory tree.

The undesirable inclusion of users' work files in System Restore started in Windows Vista, covers 574 file types, and unfortunately (and unforgivably?) there is currently no way to turn it off for particular file types or directories: [Exclude files or folders from System Restore](https://superuser.com/questions/713565/exclude-files-or-folders-from-system-restore/773300#773300).

Answer (score 0):

Your buddy has had his files deleted by the Windows System Restore wizard, the very same as if he'd hit SHIFT+DELETE himself. There are lots of users online in his position.

Try [Recuva](http://www.piriform.com/recuva) - a free file recovery tool - to do a long, full scan of the disk to see if any of his files can be recovered. If he has continued to use the disk after discovering this files were missing, the data is probably lost.

You may want to direct your buddy toward some easy and free Cloud-based backup solutions such as [Google Drive](http://drive.google.com/) and [Dropbox](http://dropbox.com/) for storing his work in as these often save a headache when situations like this arise..